# Running bash script from another in a for loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a bash script called run.sh from another called grid.sh. It works in this form:

```
#!/bin/bash
./run.sh
```

But when I put this in a for loop it fails with an error: "no such file or directory":

```
for i in {1..50}
do
  ./run.sh 50000 $i
done
```

Part of the error output is:

```
./grid.sh: line 7: /GlobalStorage/ClusterUsersStorage/aibrahim/qcdgrid_Head/run.sh 50000 1: No such file or directory
./grid.sh: line 7: /GlobalStorage/ClusterUsersStorage/aibrahim/qcdgrid_Head/run.sh 50000 2: No such file or directory
./grid.sh: line 7: /GlobalStorage/ClusterUsersStorage/aibrahim/qcdgrid_Head/run.sh 50000 3: No such file or directory
./grid.sh: line 7: /GlobalStorage/ClusterUsersStorage/aibrahim/qcdgrid_Head/run.sh 50000 4: No such file or directory
./grid.sh: line 7: /GlobalStorage/ClusterUsersStorage/aibrahim/qcdgrid_Head/run.sh 50000 5: No such file or directory
```

I don't know how to fix that.
Appreciate the help.

Comment: easiest solution is `/full/path/to/run.sh "$I"` . Else add the path of `./run.sh` to your env, i.e. `export PATH="/full/path/to:$PATH"`. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @shellter. But what is "$I" for?

Comment: Show how you run grid. Also, show the output of `ls -l`

Comment: sorry, typo, meant `"$i"`. Good luck.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I run grid using ./grid.sh. The output of ls -l is: total 6
-rwxrw-r-- 1 dmistry vtune  537 Jan  2 19:51 grid.sh
drwxrwxr-x 9 dmistry vtune   14 Jan  2 19:18 madevent
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dmistry vtune 3920 Dec 30 20:45 run.sh
-rwxrw-r-- 1 dmistry vtune   30 Jan  2 19:18 runtest.sh

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting? Copy and paste the whole thing. There's something you're not telling us. There's no reason adding a loop would cause a "no such file or directory" error to pop up.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I have added the error output above.

Comment: Please edit vital info into your question. The comment is illegible

Comment: If the error is on line 7 and you only show 4 lines of script, how do you expect to get help?

Comment: @MadPhysicist There are empty spaces which I removed when I copied the snippet here; that's why you see 4 lines but error occurring on line 7. Actually line 7 is where I run the script run.sh.

Comment: on closer reading, i think the error is in run.sh

Comment: Looks like you ran `"/GlobalStorage/ClusterUsersStorage/aibrahim/qcdgrid_Head/run.sh 50000 $i"` instead of `./run.sh 50000 $i`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assign the full pathname of `run.sh` to a variable like this:

```
run=/home/amin/run.sh   # or wherever it is...
```

Then inside the loop:

```
    ${run} 50000 $i
```

If the error "*no such file or directory*" still occurs, there's problably a typo:  correct `run=` to reflect whatever the true pathname actually is.  Since there seems to be some confusion about the true pathname of `run.sh`, use a util like [`realpath` or `readlink -e`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136494/whats-the-difference-between-realpath-and-readlink-f) to find it:

1. `cd` to the directory with `run.sh` in it.
2. do `realpath ./run.sh`, and note the full pathname output.
3. correct `run=` to use that output.

Comment: Thank you @agc. The script is now running but for some reason it is not properly reading the input arguments (50000 and $i). I'm not sure if this is related to this fix or something in the script run.sh.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Now things are running properly. Thanks @agc, your advice solved my problem. How can I vote up? It won't take my vote.

Comment: @Amin, Thanks, glad it worked out.  Re "*It won't take my vote*":  Perhaps you'd already upvoted this answer.